# Hive Warehouse Connector - Read Hive table that contain column with type array

Tags: scala, hadoop, hive

when i try te do a simple SELECT on hive table that have columns with type Array, i get this error :

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.FieldDesc.getTypeInfo()Lshadehive/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/typeinfo/TypeInfo;
    at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.util.SchemaUtil.convertSchema(SchemaUtil.java:25)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.getTableSchema(HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.java:113)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.readSchema(HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.java:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Relation$.apply(DataSourceV2Relation.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.executeQuery(HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.java:62)
    at com.orange.vodcastview.datainjector.MetaProcessorMain$.main(MetaProcessorMain.scala:34)
    at com.orange.vodcastview.datainjector.MetaProcessorMain.main(MetaProcessorMain.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out this article - https://reflectoring.io/nosuchmethod/

Usually, you're getting this error if the classpath is different during compile-time and runtime. Check what spark version you're using when you're building the project, and what's running on the environment where you deploy it.